# Subscript out of range error when using Worksheets.Activate syntax

Tags: excel, vba

I have written the below code and when debugging getting an error "Subscript out of range" for the line Worksheets("Program Mapping Sheet").Activate

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'Don't display alert
Worksheets("Program Mapping Sheet").Activate 'Set the active worksheet
Sheets("Program Mapping Sheet").Cells.Clear

Worksheets("Copied Raw Data").Activate 'Set the active worksheet
Worksheets("Copied Raw Data").UsedRange.Copy 'Copy the data

Worksheets("Program mapping sheet").Activate 'Set the active worksheet
Worksheets("Program mapping sheet").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll 'Refresh all the pivot tables


If ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then ActiveSheet.ShowAllData

Application.DisplayAlerts = True 'Display Alerts
Worksheets("Hide").Activate 'Set the active worksheet
Worksheets("Hide").Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Try refering to thisworkbook.worksheets(... and make sure sheet's name is correct. no extra spaces...

Answer (score 0):

This could be simplified like this:

```
Dim progMapSheet As Worksheet
Dim copiedRawData As Worksheet

Set progMapSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Program mapping sheet")
Set copiedRawData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Copied Raw Data")

Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'Don't display alert

progMapSheet.Cells.Clear

progMapSheet.Range("A1").Resize(copiedRawData.UsedRange.Rows.Count, copiedRawData.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Value = copiedRawData.UsedRange.Value 'Copy the data

ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll 'Refresh all the pivot tables

If progMapSheet.FilterMode Then progMapSheet.ShowAllData

Application.DisplayAlerts = True 'Display Alerts
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Hide").Activate 'Set the active worksheet
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Hide").Range("A1").Select
```

Answer (score 0):

I have attempted to replicate your issue in a new workbook and the code executed without an issue, I would review the names of your worksheets and ensure they align to your code if you are encountering this error.

As an aside, try copying and pasting the names from either the code into the sheet name or vice versa.